# .appendTo doesn't work in .bind(load) - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, append, bind

I have an issue by adding images to a div with .appendTo while I'm in a for-loop and in the .bind("load")-handler. I tried so many things but nothing worked, it only shows the last picture and not the three.
The code is pretty simple as shown below.

If anyone has a hint for me, this would be great.
Thanks in Advance!

```js
var $images = ["https://static.pexels.com/photos/769986/pexels-photo-769986.jpeg", "https://static.pexels.com/photos/767907/pexels-photo-767907.jpeg", "https://static.pexels.com/photos/746759/pexels-photo-746759.png"];

var i,
  figure,
  img;

for (i = 0; i < $images.length; i += 1) {

  figure = $('<figure />');
  img = $('<img />');

  img.attr("src", $images[i]);

  img.unbind("load");
  img.bind("load", function() {

    a = $('<a>', {
      href: this.src,
      itemprop: "contentUrl",
      'data-size': this.width + "x" + this.height
    });

    img.appendTo(a);
    a.appendTo(figure);
    figure.appendTo('#gallery-panel');
  });
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 10em;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="gallery-panel"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
img.appendTo(a);
```

to:

```
$(this).appendTo(a);
```

You're running into the [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue) because all the closures are using the same `img` variable.

Comment: thank you! This saved my life sat hours in front of this issue tried to do all crazy stuff with .append, .innerHTML, ...